# Why liquibase generate a change log with all columns specified with autoincrement=true

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

column tags all in generated changelog like this <column autoIncrement=true ...> whatever colume type is!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFGzm.jpg)

and is of course, unable to updateSQL or generate sql format changelog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYQbi.jpg)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: What version of Liquibase are you using?  What database and version are you to generate your changelog from?